# Lingering services in a docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

Say I have 50 maintenance services (as in they were created to create/delete another service's environment) that are lingering in my docker swarm (with 100 workers), as in, unused, replicas set to 0, possibly won't be used again - if required again, will be recreated automatically, if missing.

Is there any overhead in keeping them ?
Should we consider deleting them, if so, why ?

Comment: Maybe incorrect space ?